# How can one make up prayer missed due to work commitments?

Tags: salat, hanafi, salat-qada

I want to know what the ruling is if someone is working and they have missed their prayer such as Zohr or Asr or even Mughrib. How can one make up his missed prayers?

Most of the time the workplace does not have a room to make a prayer or just don't have the facilities at all. Even such workplaces are dirty and filthy. There may not even be a Masjid nearby or travelling back home is lengthy to pray the evening prayer for instance.

So, given this, how can one make up his missed prayers?

(Sunni, Hanafi view)

Comment: Oh, well. According to Hanafi school of fiqh, there is no excuse to leave the prayer in the first place...

Comment: You must make up your prayer as soon as you can preferably in the correcf order.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - thank you. So for instance as soon as I get home, I can make up the Zohr, Asr and perhaps Mughrib prayer? And how is this done? Just praying on the Fard? (i.e 4x4x3) as Qada?

Comment: Yes, but you should try your best to pray at work. Either by asking for a room or taking a pause and close your office ... as not praying on time is a sin. Dirth is no excuse as only you and the ground you pray on must be ritualy clean. And dirth is not najis by default unless it is a knosn najassa.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - unfortunately in the west (i.e UK) its not possible no matter what you do when working. Places are unclean, foul mouthed etc... etc... and pretty much haram. Also client sites don't necessarily have rooms but rather open office plans. So I can be stuck in such situations but want to make sure I make up/pray when it is possible on that day.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/20191

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think the OP misunderstood you and thought that it would be okay to purposely miss the prayer while at work! this is not what you meant, am I right?

Comment: Well as said before what defines najasa in islam are very few things, najasa is **not equal** to unclean. So you may for example pray on a ground where there's oil for example without a prayer mat. So before saying it is impossible to pray at work you should check all possibilities before searching for the last option: praying more or less the whole prayers of a day at home after work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/what-if-i-can-not-pray-due-to-my-work?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

1- **No one is allowed to miss a farz prayer purposefully**, because of any excuse, there is literally no valid excuse for this. Even in war, farz prayer is not delayed. Specially because of this excuse.

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “**The earth has been made for me a place of prayer and purification, so
>   whenever the time of prayer comes for any man of my ummah, let him
>   pray.**” Narrated by al-Bukhari, 335; Muslim, 521

And its upto you what you prefer

> “**Men whom neither trade nor sale (business) diverts from** the
>   remembrance of Allaah (with heart and tongue) nor **from performing
>   As‑Salaah (Iqaamat‑as‑Salaah)** nor from giving the Zakaah. They fear a
>   Day when hearts and eyes will be overturned (out of the horror of the
>   torment of the Day of Resurrection).
>
> **That Allaah may reward them according to the best of their deeds, and
>   add even more for them out of His Grace. And Allaah provides without
>   measure to whom He wills”**
>
> [al-Noor 24:37-38]

2- If you have your prayers missed unpurposefully), like you forgot, or was travelling on something you couldn't pray on(this one is a disputed matter among scholars though) etc. Than you will remake your missed prayers as usual. Which is better to make them in order, but not necessary, and remake them as soon as possible. And if you had missed them purposefully you also need to repent to Allah and ask for forgiveness.

Also have a look [on this question and answer.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/what-if-i-can-not-pray-due-to-my-work?rq=1)

### Allah knows best